# How to develop addin for MS Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2003, outlook-2010

How do I develop addin for MS Outlook that works with all
1. Outlook 2010
2. Outlook 2007
3. Outlook 2003

I have developed addin that works well with 2010 and 2007 BUT NOT with 2003.

I want something like this that works well with all the above three :)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `VSTO` (Visual Studio Tools for Office). [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2004/03/21/93712.aspx) is an article to get you started.

You can also check out [`Office Development Center`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You need to go for NetOffice.
It will allow you to abstract out from Outlook version.
Also it has a powerful diagnostic tool that will tell you which version of outlook your add-in is compatible with based on API features you use in your code.

Worked nicely for me.

http://netoffice.codeplex.com/