# Microsoft outlook notification

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, sms, outlook-2003

I am using .NET 2.0/3.5

Brief:

I am planing to develop an application which will send a SMS to the user mobile if he get any mail to his outlook.

Description:

I am working for a organization which has one dedicated system for an employee and they have outlook configured in their system. What I want that whenever a mail comes to their outlook they will receive a SMS on their mobile.

Now, I have SMS service with me and I need to know how can I get the notification that email is arrived to user mailbox.

Is it possible to get such type of notification from Outlook to .NET?

Comment: Is anything like RSS feed is available for Microsoft Outlook 2003 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the most complex part of your solution is sending SMS message from Outlook. In general, there are two ways to send SMS messages from a computer / PC to a mobile phone:

1. Connect a mobile phone or GSM/GPRS modem to a computer / PC. Then use the computer / PC and AT commands to instruct the mobile phone or GSM/GPRS modem to send SMS messages.
2. Connect the computer / PC to the SMS center (SMSC) or SMS gateway of a wireless carrier or SMS service provider. Then send SMS messages using a protocol / interface supported by the SMSC or SMS gateway.

Regarding first ways here you can find a lot of information: http://www.developershome.com/sms/

But this is not seems to be the right way.

Regarding second way, you can find in the first answer a lot of providers.

On my opinion, the best way for have a full programming control is using some existed provider's API or component for this issue. You can find it a lot in the internet, if you want. You also can find a usefull using  Office 2010 Mobile Service. Details you can find here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606754.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606)

Comment: The correct clickable link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606754.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can write an Outlook Addin for this purpose (although it might be better to create a serivce which resides on the email server side...).

Basically you need to subscribe to [newMail events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationevents_11_newmailexeventhandler.aspx) via [microsoft.office.interop.outlook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.aspx). Growl for windows has a ouloook addin which notifies the user of incoming mails. I am sure you can figure out how to solve your problem if you have a look at [the growl addin source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#djVkF-yFiQc/trunk/Growl%20Extras/Growl%20Outlook%20Add-In/GrowlExtras.OutlookAddIn/ThisApplication.cs&d=3).

Also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344045/how-to-develop-addin-for-ms-outlook) might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do and this may not be correct for you, but Exchange has pretty good support for mobiles already. You can use PUSH so the user receives the email immediately. There are also third-party programs to do this and SyncML extensions to Exchange to support "the rest".

You'd need a mobile phone from last millenium or so not to be able to get emails from Exchange.

http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/mobility.aspx